# Submission form will not enter certain kinds of data

Tags: php

I Created this code pretty long time ago And I've started noticing after daily usage that it doesn't enter certain kinds of data. For example when I go copy all the panagrams from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram it won't work, It will pull the defined error "Error Submitting the data". I get no "real" errors from the PHP itself. Why wouldn't this work properly? Thanks for the help.
off-sight Variables..
`$db =  mysqli_connect('localhost','xx','xxx','xxxx') or die('error with connection');`

the submission system

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
include('../includes/db_connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $newTitle = $_POST['newTitle'];
    $newPost = $_POST['newPost'];
    $newPostPreview = $_POST['newPostPreview'];
    $newCategory = $_POST['newCategory'];
    if(!empty($newPost))
        if(!empty($newTitle))
            if(!empty($newPostPreview)){
    $sql="INSERT INTO posts  (title, body, post_preview, category_id, posted)
VALUES('$newTitle', '$newPost', '$newPostPreview', '$newCategory', (now()))";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    if($query){
            echo "Post entered to database";
        }else{
            echo "Error Submitting the data";
        }
    }else{
        echo "One Or more Required forms was not filled!";
    }
}
```

textareas and stuff

```
    <br><textarea name="newPostPreview" placeholder="Post Preview(Will Be Displayed on the Index Page)" cols="100"  rows="10"/></textarea>
<br><textarea name="newPost" placeholder="Post Text" cols="100"  rows="10"/></textarea><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

note that it works fine with just plain text and english stuff, but other times it won't work for no appearent reason (just normal english posts with next to no formatting in them, won't submit..)

Comment: Debug! `$db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of issues normally comes when you are trying to insert string having special characters.So, I would like to suggest in when access post value use php function mysql_real_escape_string() like:-

$newTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newTitle']);

```
$newPost = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newPost']);

$newPostPreview = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newPostPreview']);

$newCategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newCategory']);
```

Hope this will work

Thanks

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do it with MySQLI? It needs 2 params, I searched it up on PHP and its pulling me all kinds of errors when I try to do it like it says there

Comment: Never Mind, Got it! I'm so glad! Thank you for the help too!  
`$newCategory = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['newCategory']);`